# How to automate approve function in a contract

Tags: solidity, uniswap, openzeppelin

```
Contract MyContract

function callApprove(address denomAsset, address spenderForApprove, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 denomAssetContract = IERC20(denomAsset);//for example: WETH_ADDR
      
        uint256 tokenAmountOfPool = denomAssetContract.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amount <= tokenAmountOfPool, "Not enough token in the Pool!");

        bool approveSuccess = denomAssetContract.approve(spenderForApprove, amount);
        require(approveSuccess, "Approvement failed!");
    }

    function callSwap(address denomAsset, address spenderForApprove, uint256 amountIn) public onlyOwner {
        /////// how to add this part //////////////////////////
        this.callApprove(denomAsset, spenderForApprove, amountIn);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        IMyUni myUniContract = IMyUni(myUniContractAddress);
        myUniContract.swapExactInputSingle(amountIn);
    }
```

There is a token belonging to MyContract (example WETH token). This token is requested to be swapped by the owner of MyContract. (example WETH -> UNI). First, we approve with "callApprove", then the "callSwap" function is called and the swap is done successfully.

But in the "callSwap" function, I want to call the "callApprove" function and do the approve process in it. In order not to call them separately. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I made the "callApprove" internal not public and without onlyOwner. Then I am able to call approve function inside "callSwap". Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function `public` and call it like this:

```
    function callApprove(address denomAsset, address spenderForApprove, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        IERC20 denomAssetContract = IERC20(denomAsset);//for example: WETH_ADDR
      
        uint256 tokenAmountOfPool = denomAssetContract.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amount <= tokenAmountOfPool, "Not enough token in the Pool!");

        bool approveSuccess = denomAssetContract.approve(spenderForApprove, amount);
        require(approveSuccess, "Approvement failed!");
    }

    function callSwap(address denomAsset, address spenderForApprove, uint256 amountIn) public onlyOwner {
        // this way the function is called internally
        callApprove(denomAsset, spenderForApprove, amountIn);

        IMyUni myUniContract = IMyUni(myUniContractAddress);
        myUniContract.swapExactInputSingle(amountIn);
    }
```